# Django left join with filtered relation in QuerySet for ListView

Tags: django, left-join, django-queryset

I am a Django/Python novice. I am developing a website to help me manage a small golf society. A major function of the website is to enable members to view and book their place on upcoming events.

The EventListview will display details for each event, including the venue(s) used by each event. It will also allow the member to Make/View/Modify/Cancel a booking for each event.

All of this functionality is working apart from displaying the venue(s) for each event in the EventListView.

```
members.models.py

class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    handicap = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    etc ........


events.models.py

class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    etc ........

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    details = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    start = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    finish = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    etc ........
    
    def get_venues(self):
        return mark_safe("<br />" . join([x.venue.__str__() for x in self.venue.all()]))
        
class Event_Venue(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='venue')
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='event')
    etc ........

class Member_Event(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey('members.Member', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='booking')
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='booking')
    etc ........



events.views.py

class EventListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Event
    context_object_name = 'event_list'
    paginate_by = 8
    template = 'events/event_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Event.objects.annotate(booked=FilteredRelation('booking', condition=Q(booking__member=self.request.user.member))).values('id', 'name', 'details', 'start', 'finish', 'currency', 'price', 'status', 'booked__member')



event_list.html
    .
    .
    .
    {% if event_list %}
        <table class="table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Details</th>
                <th>Venues</th>
                .
                .
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for event in event_list %}
                <td><a href="{% url "events:detail" event.id %}"> {{event.name}}</a></td>
                <td>{{ event.details }}</td>
                <td>{{ event.get_venues }}</td>
                .
                .
                <td>
                    {% if event.status == event.OPEN %}
                        {% if event.booked__member %}
                            <a class="text-primary" href="{% url "events:view_booking" event.id %}">View Booking</a>
                            <a class="text-warning" href="{% url "events:modify_booking" event.id %}">Modify Booking</a>
                            <a class="text-danger" href="{% url "events:cancel_booking" event.id %}">Cancel Booking</a>
                        {% else %}
                            <a class="text-success" href="{% url "events:create_booking" event.id %}">Make Booking</a>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% else %}
                        {% if event.booked__member %}
                            <a class="text-primary" href="{% url "events:view_booking" event.id %}">View Booking</a>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                </td>
```

The venues column is empty and I have discovered that the 'get_venues' method is not being invoked. I suspect this is because my queryset returns field values for each event object rather than the event object itself. How can I get round this problem?